# Convert array to string while preserving the quotes around the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have an array, which I want to convert to string while preserving the quotes around the elements.

For example:

```
["hello", "there"]
```

...needs to look like this as a string:

```
'"hello", "there"'
```

I can do:

```
["hello", "there"].toString()
```

But this gives:

```
"hello,there"
```

... which doesn't have quotes around the elements.

I can do:

```
["hello", "there"].join('", "')
```

... but this gives:

```
"hello\", \"there"
```

... which has backslashes in the string.

Also tried replacing those backslashes:

```
["hello", "there"].join('", "').replace(/\\/, "");
```

...but the backslashes remain:

```
"hello\", \"there"
```

Finally, we can attempt JSON.stringify:

```
JSON.stringify(["hello", "there"])
```

... only to get:

```
"[\"hello\",\"there\"]"
```

Alas, is there no solution to such misguided efforts?

Comment: Strange no-one asked... why do you need that? What are you building?

Comment: Your `JSON.stringify()` approach works. You will see the correct string if you `console.log()` it!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do with `join()` and `template literals`.

```js
function convert(arrData) {
  return `'"${arrData.join('", "')}"'`;
}

const a = ["hello", "there"];

console.log(convert(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the elements and create [an array of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from them, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array up to form a new string.

```js
const arr = ["hello", "there"];
const str = `'${arr.map(el => `"${el}"`).join(', ')}'`;
console.log(str);
```

Comment: He needs like this `'"hello", "there"'`

Answer (score 0):

Map over the array and use `JSON.stringify`, join them and surround it with quotes.

```js
"'" + ["hello", "there"]
    .map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry))
    .join(",") + "'";
```

returns

```
'"hello","there"'
```